# Want to know Restlet Routing basic concepts

Tags: java, routes, restlet

I am using the restlet routing APIs like 
http://localhost:8080/www.example.com/hello/ping
But I don't know how to use this type of method:

```
/{projectName}/{wallName}
```

that I have seen in 
[Restlet routing nightmare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682226/restlet-routing-nightmare)

Could anyone tell me

1.What is the best practice of using Restlet Routing?

2.How to implement `/{projectName}/{wallName}` in java?

3.How to get the value of `projectName` from this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there are several part within a Restlet application. Classically, this application is accessible through a Restlet component that can be created as described below:

- **Standalone mode** (outside an application server)

  ```
  Component component = new Component();
  component.setName("My component");

  component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

  MyApplication application = new MyApplication();
  // To attach application on /www.example.com
  component.getDefaultHost().attach("www.example.com", application);
  // To attach application on /
  component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(application);

  component.start();
  ```
- **Container mode (servlet support)**. You can use the extension `ext.servlet` for this use case. A front servlet is provided that automatically wraps a component. You only have to specify the class of your application implementation, as described below:

  ```
  <!-- Application class name -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
      <param-value>
          packageName.MyApplication
      </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!– Restlet adapter –>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
      </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <!– Catch all requests –>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <!-- or -->
      <!-- url-pattern>/www.example.com/*</url-pattern -->
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

You can now implement the Restlet application. For this implement, a class that extends `Application`. The routing must be defined within its method `createInboudRoot`, as described below:

```
public MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        router.attach("/{projectName}/{wallName}", MyServerResource.class);

        return router;
    }
}
```

As you can see, a server resource is attached for the path `/{projectName}/{wallName}`. This server resource is responsible to handle the request. A sample of implementation is described below:

```
public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public Representation handleGet() {
        String projectName = getAttribute("projectName");
        String wallName = getAttribute("wallName");
        (...)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Ya. It really helps me to understand.